# tex4ht: removing indentation from paragraph-continuation after block quote

Tags: tex4ht

## problem

When a paragraph contains a block quote, xelatex formats the portion after the quote, correctly, without an indent. Tex4ht, however, treats it as a new, and therefore indented, paragraph.

## MWE

main.tex:

```tex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Normal:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oldfontcommands,article]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\section{a section}

First paragraph.

Second paragraph. This one is indented. That is how it should be.
\begin{quote}
This is a block quote.
\end{quote}
This continuation of the paragraph after the block quote should not be indented. With xelatex it is not, but with tex4ht it is.

When a block quote comes at the end of a paragraph, by contrast, the new paragraph should be indented.
\begin{quote}
Here is another block quote.
\end{quote}

This is a new paragraph, so it \emph{should} be indented, to make clear that it is a new paragraph rather than the continuation of the paragraph containing the block quote.
\end{document}
```

compiling command:

```
make4ht -ux -a debug -f odt main.tex
```

xelatex output (correct):

[image]

tex4ht output (incorrect):

[image]

The key paragraph to look at is the "second paragraph."

## question

How can I make tex4ht produce the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\ConfigureEnv{quote}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
\ifnum \BegEnd:D=0
   \gHAdvance\BegEnd:N by 1
\HCode{<text:section
        text:style-name="begin-end-env"
        text:name="begin-end-env-\BegEnd:N"
       >%
       <text:p text:style-name="begin-env-p" ></text:p>}%
%
\else
   \gHAdvance\BegEnd:N by 1
\hbox{\HCode{<text:p><draw:frame
                draw:name="begin-end-env-\BegEnd:N"
                 draw:style-name="env-frame"
                 text:anchor-type="as-char"
%                 fo:min-width="0.14in"
                 svg:width="90\%"
                 draw:z-index="0"
       >
       <draw:text-box
%           fo:min-height="0.14in"
       >}}%
%
\fi
\gHAdvance\BegEnd:D by 1
}
   {\gHAdvance\BegEnd:D by -1
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi\EndP
\ifnum \BegEnd:D=0
   \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="end-env-p" ></text:p></text:section>}%
%
\else
   \hbox{\HCode{</draw:text-box>
</draw:frame></text:p> }}%
%
\fi
\par\noindent}
   {\EndP \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \bgroup \Configure{HtmlPar}
   {\EndP \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->%
%
                 <text:p text:style-name="quote\if@rl-rtl\fi
"
                         >}}
   {\EndP \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->%
%
                 <text:p text:style-name="quote\if@rl-rtl\fi
"
                          >}}
   {\HCode{</text:p>}}
   {\HCode{</text:p>}}%
%
   }
   {\IgnorePar\EndP \egroup \ShowPar \ShowIndent}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It is a copy of configuration for quotation from TeX4ht sources. Only change is that it uses

```
par\noindent
```

command at end of the third argument, to suppress indentation.

This is the result:

[image]

Edit:

To remove an empty paragraph before indented paragraph, use this build file, `build.lua`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"


local process = domfilter {
  -- this function removes empty paragraphs after quote environment
  function(dom)
    -- test if the previous paragraph style was "quote"
    local ignored_styles = {
      ["end-env-p"] = true
    }
    local prev_style 
    for _, par in ipairs(dom:query_selector("text|p")) do
      local style = par:get_attribute("text:style-name")
      -- if the previous paragraph was quote and the current paragraph is empty,
      -- then remove it
      if prev_style == "quote" then
        if not ignored_styles[style] 
           and par:get_text():gsub("%s*", "") == "" -- test if paragraph is empty
        then
          par:remove_node()
        end
      end
      -- ignore the end-env-p style, which is inserted at the end of the quote environment
      if not ignored_styles[style] then
        prev_style = style
      end
    end

    
    return dom
  end
}

-- register the filter to process the document
Make:match("4oo", process)
```

Compile using:

```
make4ht -c config.cfg -f odt -e build.lua filename.tex
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem I raised, but it looks from your screenshot that there is now no way to make the paragraph after a block quote indented. (See the last two lines of the example, which *should* be indented -- and are in the xelatex output.)

Comment: @AlexRoberts try the updated version. The downside is that it inserts blank paragraph before indented paragraph. I think this cannot be solved on the TeX level, but the empty paragraph can be removed using Lua filter.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Are you sure that tex4ht can't manage it? Xelatex does it without a problem; perhaps the same criterion for indentation could be carried over to tex4ht? That is, whenever xelatex would indent the paragraph, set the paragraph style in ODT to indented; and whenever xelatex would not indent, use the non-indented ODT paragraph style.

Comment: @AlexRoberts yes, because paragraph handling is quite difficult in the ODT output. You must do various tricks to create correct XML structure, so it doesn't matter how LaTeX itself handles it :/

Comment: I see. Well, in any case, it is certainly much easier to delete extra paragraph gaps than to go back and figure out which ones I wanted to keep indented as I was doing before. So thank you again!

Comment: @AlexRoberts I can also create a Lua filter to remove these empty paragraphs after quotes. It shouldn't be hard.

Comment: That would make it even easier! Should I ask it as another question, or do you think it makes more sense to keep it here?

Comment: @AlexRoberts I will update this one

Comment: I've tested it with the filter, and it seems to work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Update: I've realized that somehow running the lua filter prevents biber from running, so I just get citekeys rather than citations in the footnotes. With this command biber works: `make4ht -ux -f odt -c $configfile $filename.out.tex` (though there are spaces after block quotes in certain circumstances), but with this one it does not: `make4ht -ux -f odt -c $configfile -e $luafilter $filename.out.tex`. (Where the lua filter is the one in the answer above.) Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @AlexRoberts do you use a different build file to execute Biber, or do you execute Biber manually?

Comment: Well, I can tell you that the only thing I do to produce the ODT output is run that command on a tex file (which includes a line loading the package `biblatex-chicago` with the option `backend=biber`). The config file is `myconfig.cfg` as given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628208/44742) in your answer to another recent question of mine. Does that help?

Comment: I don't run a separate bash command beginning `biber`.

Comment: @AlexRoberts usually, when BibLaTeX don't show citations, it needs to run `biber` again, to get the correct `bbl` file, so it is best to try that.

Comment: but then I'm still puzzled that biber is being run automatically when I run make4ht *without* the lua filter but not when I run it *with* the lua filter. In any case, if there is no obvious fix, I can certainly just run biber manually as you suggest.

Comment: @AlexRoberts `make4ht` don't run Biber automatically, unless you use the `latexmk` extension, or if you execute it in the build file. It probably used an older `bbl` file, but BibLaTeX sometimes require the `bbl` file to be updated, then it wil show just the citekeys. You definitely don't need to run `biber` every time, just when you add new citations, or when BibLaTeX fails.